# Why does MatLab's imread() and R's readPNG() gives different results?

Tags: r, image, matlab

I want to implement PCA to image file by using R. But when I compare the results of reading an image using MatLab and R it gives different results.

```
A = double(imread('bird_small.png'));
```

using MatLab and

```
A <- readPNG('bird_small.png')
```

using R's png package gives different matrices. That made me unable to proceed on R. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

First variables of each outputs;

From MatLab >>

```
A(1,1,1:3)
```

[1] 219 180 103

From R >>

```
A[1,1,1:3]
```

[1] 0.8588235 0.7058824 0.4039216

The image is;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u2xR.jpg

Comment: How are matrices different? Perhaps you need to transpose it before processing (e.g. using `t()`)?

Comment: Difference is in the values. Column and the row numbers are equal

Comment: Please provide values from matlap output, and provide example png file (or R output).

Comment: Depending in the PNG subtype, Matlab may be returning an [indexed image](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html). If that's the case, it means you get a 2D array `A` whose values are not actual colors, but pointers to a colormap that you can get as second output of `imread`, like this: `[A, cmap] = imread('bird_small.png');`

Comment: I edited the first variables and the image. @LuisMendo I think you are right because all the variables in the matrix from MatLab is like indexes

Comment: @boyaronur Since you get a 3D array output from Matlab, it is _not_ the case that you get an indexed image. So my comment above does not apply here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[219 180 103]./255 = 0.8588    0.7059    0.4039

Apperently R has converted your png image (it contains uint8 values between 0 and 255) to floatingpoint values in the range [0-1].
To convert them back just multiply with 255.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't recognize it :)